# Multibit HD Wallet Stuck For Days (Unconfirmed)

Tags: client, multibit-hd

So MultiBit HD Wallet has been stuck for days and it's killing me. I've repaired the wallet numerous times but no luck. How can I proceed? 2nd time in the last week this has happened.. last time I was able to fix it. So I think I'm going to move wallets. Not very educated on the matter. So if anyone can tell me how to move my keys to a new wallet that would be great. Suggestions?

Image: [1](http://prntscr.com/armbu3)

Comment: So if I understand correctly there are a few transactions that are not being confirmed? Could you share the transaction hashes this concerns?

Comment: Are you using a current version of MultiBit? A lot of wallets have only recently fixed their fee estimation algorithms. You'd have to provide us some more information so we can actually understand what is happening, otherwise we're restricted to guessing. I've answered a similar question about cofirmation issues with MultiBit Classic recently, which might be of interest: [Transactions seen by peers, but not confirming](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/43567/5406)

Comment: My Bitcoin Address: 13duGc6xbazQKtLpbf5w2skGnQjjHyamjf Blockchain says everything is confirmed with 100+ confirms. (multiple transactions). As far as I know I'm up to date. About a month ago I downloaded the wallet. It's the newest not the classic. Used to have the classic, had no issues. Not sure how I can save my keys to either move wallets or upgrade/downgrade MultiBit.

Comment: I guess I'll just download Bitcoin Core and be done with it.

Comment: Solution: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53356/multibit-wallet-says-my-balance-is-unconfirmed-even-though-ive-not-sent-a-tran/