# Multibit wallet says my balance is unconfirmed, even though I've not sent a transaction in months

Tags: multibit, multibit-hd

I haven't sent any transactions for months, but my Multibit HD wallet says my entire balance is unconfirmed. I've used Wallet > Repair Wallet several times. I've close it and opened it. There is only about 1% of the balance confirmed, and it changes each time I repair the wallet.

I see that very old transactions from 2015 are showing as unconfirmed (but they are).

[image: multibit hd sucks]

I tried to install version 0.1.1 and that restored the balance, but the highest fee possible is 10,000 satoshis/KB and the current fees are 400,000 satoshis/KB so I cannot send any transactions with it.

Multibit 0.5.1

Comment: Multibit has not responded to a support request for 3 days, since May 16th.

Comment: AFAIU, MultiBit was bought by another company and the original developers have moved on. I'm not sure whether it's still being properly maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found a way! It cost me $8 and four days to switch wallets! WTF?

- Install Electrum bitcoin wallet. https://electrum.org/
- Go here and save the web page to disk: https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/
- Download, install, & start TOR browser. https://www.torproject.org/ We are using TOR because it is made for anonymity and privacy, and doesn't keep cookies, storage, cache, etc. We are going offline, but a Javascript page can store data in your browser so next time you visit, it can send your secret info back. If you are not worried and think you'll just use a private browser session, look up [permanent cookies](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) and see how creepy your browser is when it comes to protecting your data.
- Open the web page you saved in TOR browser. Turn on Javascript.
- Start Electrum, create a new wallet, and select `Import Private Keys`. Wait at the input box.
- Unplug your network cable, and disable your WiFi network connections.
- Input your Multibit seed words into the BIP39 tool. Select BIP32 tab, and MultibitHD for client.
- Scroll down and view the addresses generated. Verify the addresses match the addresses in Multibit, starting from the earliest to latest.
- Copy & paste all of the **private** keys from the private key column. Yes, you will have to freakin' copy & paste like 20-100 keys depending on how much you have been using Multibit! (Oh it get's worse!)
- These are only the original keys. Whenever you send a payment, you get change to a 'change address'. Those are not listed! If you have sent any payments, you need the change address keys also. To get the change address keys, read the following.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6btevz/how_do_i_import_my_12_breadwallet_seed_words_into/dhqvy31/?context=3

> If you use the BIP39 tool that I linked, put your seed in and go to the BIP32 tab, in the "client" box change it to "custom derivation path" and start with m/0'/0
>   You should be able to manually go through addresses and get private keys by changing the path. (example: m/0'/0 --> m/0'/1 --> m/0'/2 and I think change addresses are probably m/1'/0 --> m/1'/1 --> m/1'/2 --> etc.)

- However, the change addresses are `m/0'/1` not as mentioned above.
- Change the Client to Custom, and change the BIP32 derivation path to `m/0'/1`.
- Verify the change addresses match. To find the change address, open the first transaction where you sent, view the transaction on BlockExplorer blockchain.info, and see which address the excess change went to. This is one of your change addresses. You can verify as many as you want but more than likely if the first matches the rest do.
- Now repeat the copy & paste of the addresses **private** keys into Electrum.
- Click Next on Electrum and enter a password. *You must encrypt your wallet or else the private keys are in plain text on your disk!*
- Close TOR browser with the BIP39 tool.
- Plug in your network cable and turn on your WiFi network adapter.
- Electrum will synchronize and show your balance.
- Go to File > New/Restore and create a new wallet, with new seed words.
- Write down your seed words.
- Send your bitcoins from the old wallet to the new wallet. The fees will be high due to many inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Import your multibit wallet into Electrum to access your balance. Use the instructions below.

https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-multibithd-wallet-in-electrum/

Answer (score -2):

I saw few of your post with multibith and I had the same problems.
First you need to restore your wallet from wallet words and it will be nice if you upgrade your wallet.

Comment: WTF? I'm already using the latest version! https://multibit.org/download.html Check the version!

Comment: Sorry, I red 0.1.5 :P Have you tried restoring it from wallet words as I told you before

Comment: Yes restoring from wallet words doesn't work. The balance still shows a large unconfirmed portion.