# Multibit transaction is not being confirmed

Tags: electrum, multibit

I'm using MultiBit version 0.5.16 (is this classic?)
I am trying to get my bitcoins from Multibit to Electrum, but my transaction doesnt get confirmed. The current transaction is 1mBTC to test it first, so it's not a huge deal if I lose this 1mBTC.
I saw here something similar: [Transactions seen by peers, but not confirming](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/transactions-seen-by-peers-but-not-confirming?newreg=76a48d5c92e044e197c0fa902c848c92)
The answer there is that the version is too old.

As MultiBit is no longer supported, is it even possible to update safely, to make sure my transaction will be confirmed?

Thanks in advance,

RitchBit

Answer (score 0):

Move your private keys to Electrum. I had this issue with Multibit HD since last summer. I sent my bitcoin from Hive (which had just become unsupported) to multibit hd. For over a year the transaction showed up on multibit as unconfirmed. The steps I took were:

1. Recover the wallet words from the multibit hd wallet file
2. Use a tool online that converted the multibit wallet words to private keys
3. Added the private keys to Electrum wallet

As soon as I created the electrum wallet with the private keys it showed up as confirmed in electrum. I would completely move to another wallet altogether as multibit is deprecated, and I’ve seen this unconfirmed bug happen quite often, don’t use multibit anymore.