# Multibit transactions unconformed since august. Where is my money?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, multibit

I heard last summer that Multibit wouldn't be supported any more. So I set up a Blockchain-wallet account and tried to receive the btc to my Blockchainwallet.

4 transactions seem to be stuck somewhere. 2 are unconfirmed and seen by 26 peers and 2 others are also unconfirmed and seen by 21 peers. I've also tried one of those accelerators but apart from increasing it with one seen peer its helping me not at all.

Back in august I googled a bit about this and saw in similar discussions people advising to just 'wait it out'. However, we're december now and my BTC still seem stuck. I'm getting a bit nervous now.

1) What should I do to either get the transaction done or get my btc returned?

2) I have other BTC in my multibit wallet left: how do I move them to blockchain wallet?

[image: unconfirmed transactions]

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's due to a low fee. If you see the TX in blockchain.info or similar, you can view the satoshis per byte you paid for fee. Today (12Dec17), it's recommended to pay at least 100 satoshis per byte.

To try to fix your problem, you can reset multibit by clicking on `Tools > Reset Blockchain` and transactions, and wait to re-sync, as seen [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/transactions-seen-by-peers-but-not-confirming/43567)

Hope it helps you